# Android drawing Rect with same height on all devices

Tags: android

in Android I am trying to draw a calendar with Rect()

```
public void init(Context context) {
    bounds = new Rect();
    boundPaint = new Paint();
    boundPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#527257"));
    boundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    boundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    boundPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    boundPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    boundPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    subLinePaint = new Paint(boundPaint);
    subLinePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#a2bba5"));

    textPaint = new Paint(boundPaint);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#527257"));
    textPaint.setTextSize(Utils.dpToPx(10f, context));

    barPaint = new Paint();
    barPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    barPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (plant != null) {
        paint(canvas);
    }
}

private void paint(Canvas canvas) {
    getDrawingRect(bounds);

    Utils.reduceRectBy(bounds, MARGIN);
    canvas.drawRect(bounds, boundPaint);

    float partWidth = bounds.width() / 36f;

    // draw vertical lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            canvas.drawLine(
                    bounds.left + partWidth * i,
                    bounds.top,
                    bounds.left + partWidth * i,
                    bounds.bottom, boundPaint);

            //Paint month label
            String month = Plant.MONTHS[i / 3];
            canvas.drawText(month, (bounds.left + 12) + partWidth * i, bounds.top - 16, textPaint);

        } else {
            canvas.drawLine(
                    bounds.left + partWidth * i,
                    bounds.top,
                    bounds.left + partWidth * i,
                    bounds.bottom, subLinePaint);
        }
    }   
}
```

and in my layout I have:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="#338032"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <darksymphony.osiva.GardenCalendarView
                android:id="@+id/gardenCalendar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

On high density devices the calendar looks good, it has just enough height according to the rectangle width e.g. width: 972, height: 151 - when I print the `bounds.width()` and `bounds.height()`

But on a lower density devices (e.g. tablet), where the full width of device is lower, the height of the rectangle is very small (`bounds.width()`: 706, `bounds.height()`: 32).

So in layout for `GardenCalendarView` I increased the height to `android:layout_height="120dp"` and then in `init(Context context)` I defined parameters for Rect:

```
bounds = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
```

Now for the low density device it shows `bounds.height()` = 80 and it looks **very well**. However now, on high density device the height is very large : `bounds.height()` = 250.

So how can I draw the rectangle to look the same on all devices? I can't even set max-height, as for tablet I need different height as for high density devices

Answer (score 0):

As I did not find simpler solution, for now I solved the issue like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gardenCalendar.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getDensity();
        gardenCalendar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and then checking for device's density:

```
   public int getDensity() {

        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        if (density == 0.75f)
        {   // LDPI
            hh = 140;
        }
        else if (density >= 1.0f && density < 1.5f)
        {
            hh = 160; 
            // MDPI
        }
        else if (density == 1.5f)
        {
            hh = 185;
            // HDPI
        }
        else if (density > 1.5f && density <= 2.0f)
        {
            // XHDPI
            hh = 185; 
        }
        else if (density > 2.0f && density <= 3.0f)
        {
            hh = 235; 
            // XXHDPI
        }
        else
        {
            hh = 250;
            // XXXHDPI
        }

        return hh;
    }
```

tested on multiple density different devices, now it seems working fine.